# How to duplicate loaded *.swf without setting a class name

Tags: actionscript-3

I have read this article about abstracting assets from **ActionScript**:

[Abstracting Assets from Actionscript in AS3.0 – Asset Libraries and DuplicateMovieClip](http://blog.darylteo.com/2007/11/abstracting-assets-from-actionscript-in-as30-asset-libraries/)

But it requires to set the **Linkage Class** name. How can I get the same result without setting the linkage class name?

What I want to do is to cache a loaded asset, and use the cached version every time I request the same **URL**. A solution is to clone the loaded **DisplayObject**, but I think it's unnecessary since I only want a new copy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of **Flash 11.3**, there's a function named [getQualifiedDefinitionNames](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/ApplicationDomain.html#getQualifiedDefinitionNames%28%29) that tells me exactly what **linkage names** should I use with **getDefinition**, so there's no need to know the values beforehand.

Answer (score 1):

I think the way to do that is to use byte arrays

here's a quick sample

```
// once you load your data...
private function loaderComplete(event:Event):void
{
    var loaderInfo:LoaderInfo = LoaderInfo(event.target);
    var byteArray:ByteArray = loaderInfo.bytes; //<- this will create your byte array
}
```

you can then use `byteArray.readObject();` to generate the new class;

look at senocular's post at http://www.kirupa.com/forum/showthread.php?p=1897368
where he's got a function like this:

```
function clone(source:Object):* {
    var copier:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
    copier.writeObject(source);
    copier.position = 0;
    return(copier.readObject());
}
//that you use with 
newObjectCopy = clone(originalObject);
```

hope this gets you started

Comment: Tomorrow I will give it a try. Although, as senocular said, "This method is best used with generic objects", that's Object classes. But anyway, I will give it a try and tell you what happened. Thanks for your time!

Comment: is there a reason why you can't use the linkage ID?